# Accessing resources (fxml) in Jar from different package

Tags: java, javafx, jar, fxml

I am currently working on a project in JavaFX. I have the following folder/project structure right now:

[image]

I now have a problem accessing my .fxml files from packages other than the main package, when I compile my project into a jar. The folder layout_elements inside of the package main_interface contains all of my .fxml files.

I use the following code to load my fxml in the class main_window in my main_interface folder:

```
FXMLLoader login_loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("layout_elements/login_interface.fxml));
```

I use the following code to load fxml in a class which is not in main_interface but in the package user_interface_channel :

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLoader(getClass().getResource("/main_interface/layout_elements/chatwindow.fxml));
```

Both variants work perfectly fine when I compile and run my project in my IDE. But if I build the Project and package it into a Jar, only the first statement works. As soon as my project executes the second code snippet the program crashes with the error:

Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found.

I also tried replacing the second code by that:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(main_window.class.getClassLoader.getResource("main_interface/layout_elements/chatwindow.fxml));
```

I observe the exact same behaviour then. It works in the IDE, but crashes when packaged into a Jar.

So my question pretty much boils down to: How can I access the resources inside layout_elements from a package that is not main_interface(which is the main package) in a way that it also works when the project is compiled into a Jar?

I already tried pretty much every variant of leaving out package names, including/leaving out leading /, using getClassLoader() instead of getClass, etc. I also did not find any information regarding that problem on SO & google.

Decompiling the jar shows that all the .fxml files are included in the Jar.

Comment: Are you sure your FXML files are being deployed into the jar file? If the FXML files are in the same package as, say, `Login_controller`, you should be able to do `new FXMLLoader(Login_controller.class.getResource("login_interface.fxml"))`.

Comment: As an aside, you should use [proper naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) for your class names.

Comment: I'm quite sure, as 2 of them are loaded completly fine. It's a chat client. The login interface displays correctly, then the mainwindow displays correctly. Just when opening a chat ( which executes code not in the main package, including the second statement) it crashes

Comment: Can you list the contents of the jar file in your question? That will clarify if the fxml files are there and will also give a clearer view of the folder structure. Run `jar -t myfile.jar` from the command line or terminal, and [edit] your question to include the results.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `jar -tf myfile.jar`.

Comment: How exactly do I use the jar command in command line? I can execute my program using my_program.jar , but typing jar -tf myfile.jar only returns "unknown command" ,  I decompiled my jar using a java decompiler. It shows that all the fxml files are there.

Comment: `jar` is in the same deployment folder as `java` and `javac`. Where exactly that is of course depends on your OS and on the installation process you used to install the JDK. Typically it is in the `bin` subdirectory of the folder of the home directory of the JDK. If that's not on your path you need to specify it explicitly, e.g. on my setup (Mac OS X) I would do `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jar tf my_program.jar`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "decompiled my jar". A jar file is just a zip file: it is not compiled. Some of the entries inside it are compiled classes, of course, but the jar file is not compiled.

Comment: The bottom line is that the code you posted should work. None of your options for loading `chatwindow.fxml` from the Jar file have worked, if I read your question correctly, but they work when running from the file system (i.e. through the IDE). So it is reasonable to think that `chatwindow.fxml` is not in the jar file. So I really think you should explicitly list those contents in the question. If you can't find the `jar` executable, and you're on a UNIX-like system, you can do `unzip -l my_program.jar` (the option is a lower-case letter L).

Comment: Here is the dump of -tf myfile.jar (as images, I left out the last few statements which are just gson imports) http://imgur.com/a/4GztS . All of the .fxml files are listed there.

Comment: I'm on windows, it's called a java decompiler, it basically lists the contents of your jar file (including decompiled classes). It also shows all of the .fxml files being there.

Comment: Well that looks correct... I can't see any  reason your code isn't working in the jar file. Which class is executing the line that throws the exception?

Comment: user_interface_main.class calls that. The other fxml line which works in both IDE and jar is executed by main_window.class

Answer (score 0):

Since you have classes in the same package as the FXML files, you can use the classes in that package to access the resources. I.e. you can do

```
FXMLLoader login_loader = new FXMLLoader(Login_controller.class.getResource("layout_elements/login_interfa‌​ce.fxml"));
```

and

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(main_window.class.getResource("layout_elements/chatwindow.fxml"));
```

etc

Additionally, either of the following should work:

(`ClassLoader.getResource()` searches relative to class path)

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("main_interface/layout_elements/chatwindow.fxml"));
```

(`Class.getResource()` with leading `/` searches relative to classpath)

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/main_interface/layout_elements/chatwindow.fxml"));
```

Comment: This does not work. Using new FXMLLoader(Login_controller.class.getResource(login_interface.fxml); does not work because of wrong Location ( there needs to be layout_elements/ before login_interface. But even with layout_elements before that it shows the exact same behaviour (works in IDE, crash in Jar)

Comment: Ah, yes: OK, I misread the folder structure in the screenshot. If that doesn't work in your jar file, I am pretty convinced that at least some of the fxml files are not in the jar file. List the contents of the jar file from the command line (`jar -t myfile.jar`) and post the results in your question.